# label tag within a form is not appearning

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

in the below posted html code, the problem is the second label in the code never appears despit the first label and input appears as well as the input number 2.

please let me know how to make label2 appears again, and why it is not appearning

**html**:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <form #form="ngForm" class="clr-form  clr-form-horizontal" 
autocomplete="off">
                <div>
                    <clr-input-container>
                        <label>{{ "DISTANCE_MEASUREMENT.START_LONGITUDE" | translate }}</label>
                        <input
                            required
                            maxlength="25"
                            clrInput
                            [(ngModel)]="selectedSite.name"
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                        />
                    </clr-input-container>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <clr-input-container>
                        <label>{{ "DISTANCE_MEASUREMENT.START_LATITUDE" | translate }}</label>
                            <input
                                required
                                maxlength="25" 
                                clrInput
                                [(ngModel)]="selectedSite.name"
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                            />
                    </clr-input-container>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

Comment: dummy input after the second label?

Comment: @Jejun would you please explain what do you mean??

Comment: Why do you want to use a `label` element? It is normally associated with an `input` like the first one in your example.

Comment: @LetsamrIt add another <input /> element after label2 and see if that does anything. Labels are only meant to be used with inputs

Comment: @LukeWeaver i updated the question and the code .please have a look

Comment: This probably has to do with the `translate` pipe. If I run this HTML outside Angular it works fine. Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes around DISTANCE_MEASUREMENT.START_LATITUDE

I'm 90% sure the first label actually doesn't have those quotes